# Expand Windows Forms TreeView node without selecting it

Tags: treeview, winforms

When I expand a TreeView node by clicking on the plus sign right to it, the node gets selected. How can I avoid this? I want to be able to expand nodes without changing the selected node (like in RegEdit.exe, for example), and only change selection when the node text is clicked .

(Forgive me for what seems to be a basic question - I did search around, but found nothing. Any pointers or links are welcome.)

Comment: Getting a node selected when you click the plus sign is *not* normal behavior.  What does "right to it" mean?

Comment: It means 'left to it', sorry.

Comment: If this is not normal behaviour, then I must have enabled this from the designer by changing one of the TreeView properties. I have tried to disable it, but can't find which property affects it.

Comment: Yes, it was a bad case of PEBCAC - I did it myself in the AfterExpand event. As Hans said, this is not default behaviour. I should have posted a follow up, but I totally forgot about this thread. Sorry to have caused the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a BeforeSelect event you can tap into, which should allow you to cancel node selection if the selected node has children.

```
private void MyTreeView_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
 If (nodeWithChildren) e.Cancel = True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party with this.

You can use a Hit Test.

```
    private void myTreeView_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {

        TreeViewHitTestInfo info = myTreeView.HitTest(e.Location);

        if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label)
        {
            TreeNode node = myTreeView.GetNodeAt(e.Location);

            //do something
        }
    }
```

This will only select the node if the label is clicked.

Hope this helps.